# Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response. when add plugin shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a new wordpress plugin. This is my plugin php file,

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: User Info
 **/

function create_the_custom_table()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'students';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR(255),
    lname VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_the_custom_table');

$path = preg_replace( '/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__ );
require_once( $path . 'wp-load.php' );

function userinf()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        print $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        print $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    }
?>
    <form>
        <label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
}

add_shortcode('userinfo', 'userinf');
```

But when I try to add shortcode like this,

[image]

Getting this error,

> Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **userinf()** by as you are not returing data to the shortcode.

```
function userinf()
{
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        print $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        print $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    }
?>
    <form>
        <label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately form is not yet populate on front :'(

Comment: It is populating on my end by updating the code. May be some other code is causing the issue. If form is not being populated then what you see over there? Shortcode?

Comment: Nothing and I have activated the plugin too